# How can I send parameter to Flask restful service constructor?

Tags: python, rest, flask, python-requests

I am trying to send name and surname parameters via :

http://0.0.0.0:5859/product/mike/scott But result is with error :

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Product(Resource):
    def get(self,name,surname):
        return {
                'product': ['Ice Cream',
                            'Chocolate',
                            'Fruit'],
                'name':name,
                'surname':surname

                }

api.add_resource(Product,'/product/{name}/{surname}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5859, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this block from:

```
api.add_resource(Product,'/product/{name}/{surname}')
```

to:

```
api.add_resource(Product,'/product/<name>/<surname>')
```